How to open bluetooth settings on Google Pixel with Android 14?
I want to open the bluetooth settings by sending an Intent with action Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS on Google Pixel devices with Android 14.
It works e.g. on Samsung devices. However, on Google Pixel devices it does not open the correct screen. Instead it opens "Connected devices"
Connected devices
Is it somehow possible to open the "real" bluetooth settings?
Bluetooth settings
The problem can also be reproduced with adb
adb shell am start -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS


You need to replace android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS with android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS to get it working as expected like this:
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));

and add BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission to the Manifest.

This is just the String value inside ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS "android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS"... from the app I use ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS

Also my app uses BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission, but I don't think you need it for this usecase. Also it works in general, just on Google Pixel it opens the "wrong" screen, but on other devices it works fine.

that's fine about the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission but, did the rest of the answer work for you?

Not really, because it is the same. ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS is the name of the constant, "android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS" is the string value. In the app I already use ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS but in adb you have to use the plain String.
